# Showing soft keyboard in devices when focus() not working

Tags: angular, input, keyboard, focus, device

Angular 2 + Typescript web app:

The problem is the following:

I found out that, after focusing an element using a `@ViewChild` or getting the element by tag or id with `.focus()`, it wasn't exposing the soft keyboard in iOS and Android devices.

I figured out that the problem was that either with `*ngIf` or `display: none` after the element is shown again, for some reason it doesn't triggers the soft keyboard in the devices.

A workaround is setting an `[ngClass]` to set styles like: 
`opacity: 0;` plus removing the margins and paddings. But this way it was scrolling when focusing and exposing the keyboard.
So I had to just add a `position: absolute` + `bottom: 9999px` to avoid the scroll.

I wonder if there is a different (less hacky) solution I could use for this

Thanks!

edit:

the hidden element is it's parent's parent like this:

`<mr-navbar [ngClass]="{'local-fixed-header': isHeaderFixed(), 'local-non-fixed-header': !isHeaderFixed()}"
               *ngIf="canShowHeader()"></mr-navbar>`

So the input is within a child of `mr-navbar` called `smb-component` which is:

`<input id="searchInput" #searchInputMobile placeholder="{{ Home.SEARCH_HELP_TEXT_MOBILE | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="searchText"
                 (focus)="onSearchInputFocus($event)" (focusout)="onSearchInputFocusOut($event, Home.SEARCH_HELP_TEXT_MOBILE)"
                 (keyup)="loadSearchModalWithInput($event)"
                 class="search-input visible-xs" tabindex="{{ searchTabIndex }}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

in HTML:

```
<p *ngIf="editing != id" (dblclick)="display(id)">
    {{title}}
</p>
<input #input *ngIf="editing===id" [value]="title" (blur)="hide()" >
```

in your class :

```
  ...
  @ViewChild('input') private input;
  shouldFocus = false;
  ...
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.shouldFocus) {
        this.input.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    this.shouldFocus = false;
  }

display(index) {
    this.editing = index;
    this.shouldFocus = true;
  }

  hide() {
    this.editing = null;
    this.shouldFocus = false;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Vega but there is no issue with the focus itself, the problem is that if the element is hidden it won't show the keyboard whatsoever. I even try adding a timeout (like 3 seconds) after showing the element and It doesn't expose the keyboard either (the focus works)

Comment: How about triggering         this.shouldFocus = true; after the element is shown again. Because forcing the focus() should force the sofkeyboard to come on front. At least that's how it worked for me in IOS.

Comment: That actually works, but without showing the keyboard though. I tried never changing shouldFocus to false and it shows the keyboard (maybe that's a good clue to figure out a fix, like a timeout or something)

Comment: nvm, it isn't working the first time even if I never change the `shouldFocus` back to false, so this way isn't working either...

Comment: too bad... I will look closer to see if I can help

Comment: I reviewed my answer and saw an error, my bad. I am not sure you corrected by yourself already or not, but I updated my answer. Also, I remember adding autofocus on the element helped.

Comment: yes I tested with autofocus as well and it didn't work. Check this out: https://caniuse.com/#search=autofocus

Comment: I updated the answer by a (very simplified) code that actually works for me. The idea is that double clicking on the label should've trigger the activation of the input for an edit. It should get the focus and the keyboard should be shown. Could you try to implement this almost as is in your code to see and eventually adapt it for you?

Comment: Thanks again Vega, I'll give it a try ASAP

Comment: Vega. I'm not sure I follow your answer... I added more info to the original question to see if you can give me a clue about how to apply your solution. Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry, I went away and forgot. I will take a look again!

Comment: Could you try  setTimeout(()=>{this.searchInputMobile.focus()},1000); please? Could you try to set up a plunker or something equivalent to test please?

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work... I also tried with even 3 seconds to give the element time to show up. I'll try to set a plunker